# проблема с кодом в django

Tags: python, django

Возникла проблема, никак не могу разобраться. Есть код на python django

views.py

```
def c_g(request, id_g):    
 return render(request, 'c_g.html')
```

urls.py

```
path('id:<int:id_g>/', views.c_g, name='c_g'),
```

c_g.html

```
{% extends "login/wrapper.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-top: 20px;">
  <div class = "container">      
    <div class="card border-0 shadow my-5">
      <div class="card-body p-5">
        <!-- Выбор группы -->
      {% if c_g %}
      TEST!      
      {% endif %}      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div class = "container">  
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Не выводится надпись TEST! ходя на других страницах он отображает всю необходимую информацию. как я понимаю if не видит что используется часть кода из view.py def c_g

Comment: Вы не передаёте в контекст шаблона переменную `c_g`, соответственно выражение `{% if c_g %}` ложно.

Answer (score 1):

В шаблоне используются переменные из контекста(https://djbook.ru/rel1.8/topics/http/shortcuts.html#render). Добавить c_g в контекст можно в файле views.py:

```
def c_g(request, id_g): 
    context = {'c_g': True}   
    return render(request, 'c_g.html', context=context)
```

В функции path необязательно использовать названия c_g. Она принимает два параметра: запрошенный адрес URL и функцию, которая обрабатывает запрос по этому адресу. Дополнительно через третий параметр указывать имя маршрута.